# How to add values on bar chart in python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I made a bar chart in Python but I cannot add the values on each of the bar. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
yelp_area=df.groupby('Area').Yelp_rating.mean()
    
yelp_area.plot(kind='bar' , rot=0, alpha=0.8, figsize=(10,6), color='r')

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

plt.ylabel('Average Rating on a 1-5 scale')
```

[I attached the picture of the bar chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Py8H.png)

Comment: see [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addlabels` in it:

```
# importing library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# function to add value labels
def addlabels(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i]//2,y[i], ha = 'center',
                 Bbox = dict(facecolor = 'white', alpha = .5))
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # creating data on which bar chart will be plot
    x = ["Engineering", "Hotel Managment", "MBA",
         "Mass Communication", "BBA", "BSc", "MSc"]
    y = [9330, 4050, 3030, 5500,
         8040, 4560, 6650]
      
    # setting figure size by using figure() function 
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
    
    # making the bar chart on the data with color red
    plt.bar(x, y, color = 'red')
      
    # calling the function to add value labels
    addlabels(x, y)
      
    # giving title to the plot
    plt.title("College Admission")
      
    # giving X and Y labels
    plt.xlabel("Courses")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Admissions")
      
    # visualizing the plot
    plt.show()
```

Which gives you this result.- [Attached Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEMI9.png)

You can refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart/) for more detailed information.